# Grid View dentro de Fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, gridview

bueno estoy haciendo una aplicación en donde quiero poner un gridview en un fragment el problema está en una línea de código que me marca error 
Este es el código:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AccionFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accion, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(AccionFragment.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mconxtext;

    public ImageAdapter (Context c) {
        mconxtext = c;
    }

    public ImageAdapter(AccionFragment accionFragment) {
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbsIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem (int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mconxtext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240,426));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbsIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

        private Integer[] mThumbsIds = {
                R.drawable.spiderman,
                R.drawable.blade_runner_2049,
                R.drawable.guardianes_de_la_galaxia_vol2,
                R.drawable.john_wick,
                R.drawable.jumanji,
                R.drawable.liga_de_la_justicia,
                R.drawable.mujer_maravilla,
                R.drawable.rapidos_y_furiosos,
                R.drawable.thor_ragnakor
        };
}
```

}

Donde me marca error es aquí:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accion, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(AccionFragment.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Que debo de hacer

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en que estas enlazando la vista del `GridVeiw` llamando el método `findViewById()` de la actividad a la que pertenece el fragmento.

```
GridView gridView = (GridView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

Para enlazar la vista del `GridView` debe utilizar el objeto `view` que almacena la vista del layout.

```
GridView gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

De esta manera tu código quedaría así.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accion, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    // ...

    return view;
}
```

#### Actualización

Al `Toast` tienes que pasarle el contexto de la actividad, el cual obtienes con el método `getActivity()`.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Yo digo en el Toast

Comment: @JavierDavid he actualizado mi respuesta.